# How to inject JavaScript into a browser with Frida?

Tags: windows, frida

I'm learning how to use Frida, and would like to do something basic like inject JavaScript into a browser on Windows to [list all running tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getAll). It seems like it should be possible as Frida allows you to

> inject snippets of JavaScript into native apps on Windows, Mac, Linux,
>   iOS and Android,

but almost all of the articles online deal with how to use it for Android or iOS and I haven't found anything relevant to my scenario.

If my understanding of the situation is incorrect, please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

You understand the situation incorrect.

`windows.getAll()` is JavaScript which the client, in this case, Firefox browser, is evaluating.

Using Frida is injecting JavaScript code into Firefox.

```
$ cat script.js
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "PR_Write"), {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log(Memory.readByteArray(args[1], args[2].toInt32() - 1));
    }
});
$ firefox &
[1] 4321
$ frida -p 4321 -l script.js
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  0123456789ABCDEF
00000000  33 62 2f 32 bf eb 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 03 5c 90  3b/2..........\.
00000010  f5 48 5c 90 f5 48 40 2a ec a1 5e 6a 82 e6 00 00  .H\..H@*..^j....
00000020  00 46 00 00 00 00 3a 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 77  .F....:https://w
00000030  77 77 2e 67 73 74 61 74 69 63 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 72  ww.gstatic.com/r
```

You can also invoke functions manually, override & intercept (inject code before & after execution).

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty examples of using Frida on Windows:

- [Windows example](https://vicarius.io/blog/wtf-is-frida/)
- Huge collection of Awesome Frida links - [link](https://github.com/dweinstein/awesome-frida/blob/master/README.md)
- [Windows example 2](https://bachs.tistory.com/entry/Windows-HookingFrida) in Chinese so use Google Translate.

To your question, the general idea behind Frida is the same regardless of the platform where you have to make yourself familiar with [Frida API](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/) and write scripts to analyzed hooked functions according to a platform you are working on. For the most part you will be fine using JS based API which enables to call native functions of a particular platform. @Iddo example demonstrates it.